# How do I connect a Go script with Gotron frontend when making a GUI?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, go

I have been following this tutorial online about how to make a GUI using Go:
https://medium.com/benchkram/tutorial-adding-a-gui-to-golang-6aca601e277d
and i was wondering how i can connect html input to my backend that is written in Go.
I hope this makes sense.
Any links or help would be very much appreciated.

The code:

```
package main
import (
    "github.com/Equanox/gotron"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new browser window instance
    window, err := gotron.New("webapp")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Alter default window size and window title.
    window.WindowOptions.Width = 1200
    window.WindowOptions.Height = 980
    window.WindowOptions.Title = "Gotron"

    // Start the browser window.
    // This will establish a golang <=> nodejs bridge using websockets,
    // to control ElectronBrowserWindow with our window object.
    done, err := window.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Open dev tools must be used after window.Start
    // window.OpenDevTools()

    // Wait for the application to close
    <-done
}
```

Comment: And what the heck is a Go *script*? Go is a compiled language. Just because you happen to be able to run `go run main.go` does not make it an interpreted language.

Comment: With "connect html input to my backend", do you mean stuff like form submissions? You'll probably need to start a http server in another goroutine and then handle it like a normal server application using `net/http`, then point your gotron window to it using the [`LoadURL` function](https://godoc.org/github.com/Equanox/gotron#BrowserWindow.LoadURL)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code that the tutorial relies on is no longer maintained and likely a malware. However, if you look in the official golang documentation, [which you can find here,](https://golangr.com/gui/) you can find several ways to provide an html/css frontend to golang gui applications.

They suggest using gowd, go-astilectron or go-sciter, which are all well documented and there are several tutorials to quick start your gui project.

These systems work well, but they have the downside of creating very large binaries that may complicate distribution. As an alternative you can try using [Qt bindings](https://github.com/therecipe/qt) or [Gtk bindings](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3) for go.